# Are complete sublattices of algebraic lattices algebraic?

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

If $L$ is an algebraic lattice with a complete sublattice $T$, must $T$ be algebraic? I suspect that it must not be, but am struggling to find a natural counterexample.

As supremums are preserved in $T$, compact elements of $L$ in $T$ are compact in $T$. Thus, if $T$ is to not be compactly generated, $T$ must not contain some compact elements of $L$. However, in each of my cursory attempts at formulating $T$, new elements became compact in $T$ relative to $T$, so that $T$ was once again compactly generated.

Comment: What do you mean by complete sublattice – preserving infs and sups or…?

Comment: Yes, exactly - a sublattice that preserves the sups and infs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $L$ be a complete lattice and let $T$ is a subset of $L$ that is closed under infima.
Then $T$ will also have suprema, though the inclusion $T \hookrightarrow L$ need not preserve them.
Define $f : L \to T$ by
$$f (x) = \inf {\{ t \in T : x \le t \}}$$
By construction, $x \le f (x)$, and $f (x) \le t$ if and only if $x \le t$.
Hence, $f : L \to T$ preserves suprema.

Now suppose the inclusion $T \hookrightarrow L$ preserves directed suprema.
Then $f : L \to T$ also preserves compact elements.
So if $x \in L$ is the supremum (in $L$) of the compact elements (in $L$) under it, then $f (x)$ is also the supremum (in $T$) of the compact elements (in $T$) under it.
Thus, we have proved:

**Proposition.**
If $L$ is an algebraic lattice and $T$ is a subset of $L$ that is closed under infima and directed suprema, then $T$ is also an algebraic lattice.